# PDO Fetch with while and foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I used all both of your tipps:
Changed to that but the Mysql Statement doesnt get the value...

Look that:

```
try {
  $sql = "SELECT a_idname FROM t_users WHERE a_zone_num <> -1;";
  $users = $conn3->query($sql);
  while ($row = $users->fetch()) {
    $result = $users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $value) {
      echo $value;
      $Add_Cash = $conn1->prepare("UPDATE bg_user SET cash = cash + ':cash' WHERE user_id = ':result';");
      $Add_Cash->bindParam(':cash', $cash);
      $Add_Cash->bindParam(':result', $value);
      $Add_Cash->execute();
      $Count++;
    }
  }
  $conn3 = null;
}
catch (PDOexception $e) {
  echo "Error is: " . $e-> etmessage();
}
```

Comment: `SELECT a_idname FROM t_users WHERE a_zone_num <> -1;`??? is this what you mean?

Comment: really -.- sorry next time i need to think about more time But thank you really much i reworked the code more than 2 hours lol...

Comment: But it doesnt still works -.-

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  (I think you may have edited your post and removed the actual question you were asking.)  What is the output you are seeing, and what is the output you *want* to see?

Comment: Atm i see 1 long string with every user user1user2user3 but if i add $value to mysql statement below its doesnt work                     $Add_Cash = $conn1->prepare("UPDATE bg_user SET cash = cash + ':cash' WHERE user_id = ':result';");
        $Add_Cash->bindParam(':cash', $cash);
        $Add_Cash->bindParam(':result', $value);

Comment: So i want to see that i get it working that i can add $Add_Cash->bindParam(':result', $value); And in $value is the a_idname and if i use my mysql string it update my database for every user

Comment: are you assigning $cash to anything? it does not seem to be assigned to a value.

Comment: I had get it now to work there are some faults in Mysql Bind. I had to use :cash instead of ':cash' But now i get the error it doesnt grap all only every 2. Entry of db lol ...

Comment: it grabs every 2 because you are calling $users->fetch() twice once inside while and anther after the while statement. you should change $row = $users->fetch() to $result = $users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) inside while and remove the second one.

Comment: Ahh k thanks dont seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your $sql to

```
$sql = "SELECT a_idname FROM t_users WHERE a_zone_num <> -1;";
```

Comment: Done but now i get with this Code look i edited on top.